# Как вывести значение с таблицы бд

Tags: php

```
<?php

$host = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$db_name = "";
$tbl_name = "";

mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die("can't connect");
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die(mysql_error());

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

?>
```

Вот подключение, а как вывести потом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
   print($row['colname']);// вывод значения ячейки столбца с именем colname
}
```

Дублирующий вопрос: на вопрос неоднократно отвечали в контексте других проблем. Хотя бы тут: 31643

P.S. Ты опять за свое?